# Replacing a regex with a string in Objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a piece of text coming from a web service.
I want to remove all the occurrences of a `comma` by a `comma followed by a space`.

If the text is `One,Two,Three` I want to make it `One, Two, Three`.

I was using:-

`[sectionTitle stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"," withString:@", "];`

BUT this will replace every ',' with ', '. If the space is already there then this replacement should not happen.

Is there a regex version of the above method ?

How would you accomplish this ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code for doing this:

```
NSString *yourString = @"123, 456,789,   012";
NSError *err = NULL;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@", {0,}" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&err];
NSString *modifiedString = [regex stringByReplacingMatchesInString:yourString options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [yourString length]) withTemplate:@", "];
NSLog(@"%@", modifiedString);
```